# Pattern Recognition using Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, pattern-recognition

I have many evolution curves (on time), of a system as images. 
These evolution curves are plotted when the system behave in a normal way ('ok'). 
[image: sample evolution curve]

I want to train a model, which learn the shapes of the curves (or parts of the shapes) when it behave in a normal way, so it will be able to classify new curves to normal (or abnormal).

Any ideas of the model to use, or how to proceed ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can perform [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), and then classify. Also look for [functional data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis)

Here is a nice [getting started guide with PCA](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/principal-component-analysis/)

Comment: Thank you Mitchapp, 
I have only two dimension in my data (x: time, y: 2sd dim) so why PCA ? 
Do you have an idea of model to classify ? 
Thank you

Comment: when you reduce dimensions, curve will become linear, then apply any classifier KNN, SVM...etc you want

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with labeling (annotating) the images. The label can be as Normal/ Not Normal as 0/1 or as many classes you want to divide the data into.

Since it's a chart so the orientation is important, a wrong orientation can destroy the meaning of the image. 
So make an algorithm which always orient the chart in the same way while reading.

Now that the labeling is done you need to train these images for correct classification.

- Augment the data if needed
- Find a image classification model
- Use the trained weights
- feed you images and annotations in the desired format
- Train the model
- Check for the output error or classification errors.
- Create an evaluation matrix like confusion matrix in case of classification.
  If the model is right and training is properly done you will get good accuracy.
  Otherwise repeat the steps.

This is just an overview, with this you can start towards your goal.

Comment: Thank you @Amit Gupta, very clear and interesting. 
Do you have any idea of image classification models to use for this type of problems?

Comment: It depends how much data you have. If you have 10s of GB of data then you should go for Deep Learning Models, if the data is not that high either you can augment the data (which I don't suggest in the graph case) or you can use CNN models. use VGG-16. Or write your own model.

Comment: @AmitGupta you should not consider a curve as an image. Curve is nothing but a number of data points (x,y) where y  is a multivariate point.

Comment: @Mitchapp I am not considering the curve as image, he mentioned that all the data is available as image.